# How to AngularJS to send get request via ajax request and upon success remove a tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Lets say I have this in my view:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Result 1</p>
        <a>Delete Result 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Result 2</p>
        <a>Delete Result 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Result 3</p>
        <a>Delete Result 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And onclick I want to call an ajax function and pass it a parameter and upon success, delete that row.

I know how to do this with some lengthy jquery, but I am in the process of learning Angular.

Comment: What angularjs code do you have so far? You can use `$http` to make the call.

Comment: Nothing. All I know so far is to declare ng-app somewhere. I haven't the faintest idea what to put in my <script> tag. I do know how to write the ajax request in typical jquery fashion tho

Comment: It's really hard to help you if you haven't shown any effort >.>

Comment: **All I know so far is to declare ng-app somewhere** You can not do anything with angular if you don't learn angular